# Validation of domain model: how and where

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

A typical EF+MVC system will have two or three levels of validation:

1. For ViewModel: input / physical validation (DataAnnotations, FluentValidation), in other words, length, null, range, regex, etc.
2. For Model: input / physical validation (repeat of 1 in case MVC is not used and data comes from another system, WCF, forms, etc.)
3. For Model: logical / "business rules" validation

I can't find best practices for validation of 2+3 for the actual Model / entities / domain / "business rules". We either:

- put simple validation rules in an entity's property setter (but this is really messy)
- hook into EF's `SaveChanges()`, and if an entity is in the `Added` or `Modified` state then trigger validation (which validates the entire entity at once)

This is hard to maintain. A lot of thought went into ViewModel validation, but for Model validation it is domain-specific and so it is for you to determine a creative solution, and mine is not that great.

- Are there better ways to do this, or helpful tools (like maybe DataAnnotations or FluentValidation but for domain entities)?
- Where is the best place to do model validation or to trigger the model's validation?

Comment: I don't understand your "levels".  What do you mean by "physical validation"? I don't understand what the difference is between 1 and 2. Are you referring to client-side and server-side validation?  There is no middle "logical layer" validation system in MVC, in fact MVC doesn't provide any functionality for that.  There is validation at the data layer though, which validates against the data model (which is not a logical model)

Comment: My question is not specifically concerned with client/server. 1 means validating input: null/length/range/etc. Then 2 is the same thing, but what if the data came from WCF or another system, then 1 didn't happen so you would perform input/physical validation AGAIN to be safe. Ignore all that, what I really need to understand is how people are doing 2+3 for the domain.

Comment: Your premise is wrong, therefore your questions based on that premise is wrong.  MVC does not provide any validation for the model.  It only provides validation for the view model.  EF provides validation for the Data model.  The business layer or domain model is outside of either EF or MVC and is entirely under your control as to how to do validation.

Comment: My premise is not wrong. I specifically explained this has nothing to do with MVC in particular. We use the data layer in our MVC system, as well as in a non-MVC system. I need to know how to validate the data layer, in an automatic and elegant way as is done for MCV's ViewModels.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the data model (entities) with the business layer (domain model).  Those are two different things.  The domain model is a virtual model that is modeled after the domain requirements.  The Data model is modeled after the physical database structure (although to some extent EF offers the ability to abstract the physical model into by using inheritance types, but this isn't a true logical model because it's still very dependent upon physical structure)

Comment: We are arguing semantics, but if you remove the offensive word "logical" then the question still applies. Validation of a Model (possibly, using logical/business rules) is not as straightforward as validation for the ViewModel.

Comment: Validating your business layer is as straight forward as you want to make it, because you are in control of it.  Your premise is that because MVC provides a nice way to validate view models, means that everything else is not "straightforward" ignores the fact that it's not MVC's responsibility to do anything about your business or data layers.  Just because MVC provides nice tools for it's responsibilities does not make business rule validation harder.  It just doesn't make it easier.  You have always had to do business rules the hard way.

Comment: True. But that is what people said until they used aspect oriented programming, DataAnnotations and tools like FluentValidator. I am looking for a better way. If there is none (yet), that is ok as an answer.

Comment: Nothing stops you from using FluentValidation in your business logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A typical MVC+EF system will have 3 layers, but they aren't what you're talking about.

1. Presentation Layer (input/output)
2. Business Layer (Logical layer)
3. Data Layer (model represents low-level data)

MVC provides validation for layer 1.  EF provides validation for layer 3.  There is no validation functionality provided by either MVC or EF for layer 2.  If you want validation there, you have to do it yourself, or use a third party business object framework.

Validation in layers 1 and 3 are separate, even though in many cases they may have similar validation.  The reason is that validation is accomplished in different ways, and with different requirements.

For example, you may have a field in your database that is nullable for data modeling or business logic reasons (let's say some data is pre-loaded and the user is required to update the field as part of the business process).  The data layer says it's nullable, but you want your UI to make it required.

EDIT:

Simply put, the Data model should not be enforcing business rules.  Therefore, you should not need any validation in the data model, other than to validate against the physical data model (ie, if the field is nullable, the data type in the model should nullable, otherwise not).  In most cases, you physically cannot insert invalid (from the data models perspective) data because the code model will not allow it.  The only exception to this is string variables, which can obviously overflow the size constraints of the physical model, but if that happens then an exception gets thrown anyways.

Your middle tier, the business layer, should be where you need to validate business rules (for example, that a customer purchase order must start with a letter).  Neither MVC or Entity Framework, or WCF or whatever provide any way to do this validation.

There is a bit of a disconnect here, because the business rules should (in theory) drive the presentation layer validation.  But, MVC has no built-in functionality to do that, though.  So you end up duplicating your business rules in the UI.

There is at least one third party business object framework that tries to deal with this.  CSLA.  They provide a custom MVC model binder that ties in the business objects with the UI to do validation, but this is just using the built-in extendibility of MVC to do this.

So, if you don't want to use a dedicated business object framework, you are stuck either duplicating validation between UI and Business layer, or trying to figure out your own way to make your own business layer control UI validation.

Comment: As I mentioned in above comment, the question is not about MVC. It was brought in to explain that MVC validation for ViewModels is designed pretty well, and is elegant and almost automatic. I want the same thing for our domain, or the M in MVC.

Comment: I agree with your points, but it still leaves the question open. Which is simply: where and how is a good way to physically validate my entities (format, nullability, etc.) and logically validate my entities (against business rules). I explained how we already do it, which works, but is not elegant and difficult to maintain. I am wondering if others are using a different approach.

Comment: @BobbyB - I'm still confused about what you want.  The entity code model will not allow you to insert things that are of the wrong format, won't allow you to insert nulls into non-nullable fields, won't allow you to insert characters into numeric fields, won't let you insert invalid dates, etc..  And when you manage to slip by the few holes there are (for instance, over or underflowing the date precision) it will throw an exception.  Same goes with trying to insert more characters than a field can contain, or whatever.

Comment: And again, the middle business/domain layer is independent of either MVC or EF.  The framework provides no facility to do validation on that, so you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Yes I am asking about logical business rules. If datetime is on a public holiday, then business is closed, so only allow the next working day, etc. I explained that there is no built-in way to do this, and my question was how are others doing it and where. We do it in property setters and by intercepting SaveChanges. Are there are better ways or tools. The question was very simple.

Comment: PS I disagree to allow EF to perform physical validation- you shouldn't let bad data get so far down into the system. That is why we prefer to perform the physical validations up front (even though in an MVC environment, it could be duplication of some validation on the ViewModels).

Comment: Yes although we disagreed on some of the wording, I agree with your edit, it seems there is no clean way to do this. We encapsulated all the business rules in a data access compositor layer which controls access and checks whats is entering/exiting the data layer. It is called from the EF's SaveChanges method. But I like the way there are easy to use hooks in the MVC structure. I hoped there is something organised for doing validation in the domain.

Comment: @BobbyB - I very strongly disagree that placing this validation in SaveChanges is the correct way to do this.  The reason is that it violates separation of concerns and creates tight two-way coupling between your business and data layers and back again.  Now your data model must know about your business model and your business model must know about your data model.  You may as well not even have a separation if you're going to do that.  The data layer should be responsible ONLY for enforcing the physical data constraints.

Comment: Ok now that is the discussion I originally wanted! :) So where do you recommend to do it?

Comment: @BobbyB - By the way, this is the reason that many people prefer to not use stored procedures for business logic, because they want their business rules to live in the business layer, not in a completely separate subsystem written in a different language on a different platform.

Comment: Guys, encapsulate your data access in Repositories and use an unitofwork to handle you commits. In additon build a service layer to validate your business logic before the unitofwork commits.

Comment: @BobbyB - Business object validation can occur in either the getters and setters for the properties, or it can occur in the commands that the business objects support (ie `ProcessPurchaseOrder()` or `GetCustomerBalance()`.  Or you could abstract things to a more general "BusinessRule" class (or use a business rule framework)

Comment: @garfbradaz - Repositories and UnitOfWork are data access patterns, not businesss layer patterns.  Your data layer uses those to abstract the data access and reduce coupling.  It does not provide what we're talking about, which is business rule validation.  What most people call a "service layer" is simply a façade to the business layer, unless you're actually using services like WCF or ria.  These are all interface patterns, and not related to what we're discussing.  They cover the borders between layers.

Comment: @garfbradaz Agree with Mystere Man on this, the Repository pattern (typically) sits on top of the data, but doesn't include business rules (ie rules which have nothing to do with the data per se, but with what that data logically represents). We use them, but I wanted to know where the business logic and associated validation will occur.

Comment: I think the most elegant way so far, is to do what we do already: we decorate the properties with custom Attributes which define various rules. Since they have access to multiple properties and the underlying data, we can also reuse them on different properties. BUT, I think we will continue to hook onto SaveChanges, because that way we have a failsafe just before comitting changes. Yes it's not clean, but then that was why I asked this question. And a BR framework is too heavy for our needs.

Comment: @Bobby B: When you have come up with a Solution, let me know. I would be interested to hear what you implement. :)